# Counting strings after pre processing of a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Have a pandas dataframe:

```
       text
["string1","sttring2"]
["string","string3"]
["string2"]
```

I am running this code to extract the strings in the `df['text']` column:

```
strings_list = set(df['text'].str.extractall('\"([^"]+)\"')[0])
```

And I get a list of distinct string: `string1`, `string2`,`string3`, `string`

**What I need from here:**

I need to count how many times each of these string appears in the whole dataframe.
**My problem** is that some rows, as you can see, has more than one string and also I need to remove the `[]` and `""` and split then individually.

**In the example above, the output should be:**

```
string1 : 1,
string2 : 2,
string3 : 1,
string  : 1
```

I am having a hard time to do this task.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['"string1","string2"'],['"string","string3"'],['"string2"']], columns=['text'])    
word_count = {}
strings_list = set(df['text'].str.extractall('\"([^"]+)\"')[0])
for word in strings_list:
    word_count[word] = df.text.str.count('"' + word + '"').sum()

print(word_count)
```

Comment: You solution worked as a charm!  Do you mind to help me how can I save this list+count in a variable?  Huge thanks

Comment: Updated the answer. Word and count is now put to a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

We can try `explode` then `value_counts`

```
out = df.text.explode().value_counts()
Out[49]: 
string2    2
string1    1
string3    1
string     1
Name: text, dtype: int64
```

In case you have str

```
import ast

df.text.map(ast.literal_eval).explode().value_counts()
Out[54]: 
string2    2
string1    1
string3    1
string     1
Name: text, dtype: int64
```

Comment: your solution does not work because does not split the string when a row has more than one string! Thx though

Comment: @pouchewar import ast
df.text.map(ast.literal_eval).explode().value_counts()

Comment: @pouchewar you can check the update

Comment: Now you solution worked fine!! Huge Thanks man!

Comment: you solution is the fastest one and more elegant but I already had accepted another answers, but I will use yours. Thanks again mate.

Comment: @pouchewar no worry glad I can help ~

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[["string1","string2"]], [["string","string3"]], [["string2"]]], columns=['text'])
print(df)
mylist = [t for text in df['text'].values for t in text]
print(mylist)
print(collections.Counter(mylist))
```

Output:

```
                  text
0   [string1, string2]
1   [string, string3]
2   [string2]

['string1', 'string2', 'string', 'string3', 'string2']

Counter({'string1': 1, 'string2': 2, 'string': 1, 'string3': 1})
```

Example 2:

```
import ast
import collections
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['["string1","string2"]'],['["string","string3"]'],['["string2"]']], columns=['text'])
temp = [ast.literal_eval(text) for text in df['text'].values]
mylist = [t for text in temp for t in text]
print(collections.Counter(mylist))
```